# vim delete to tab character key

Tags: vim

In vim I can delete from current cursor position up to a certain character, say g, using `dtg`.  How do I delete up to the next tab char though?  Is there a key to represent a tab in that situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing

> <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

does what was requested (for me, using vim 7.2).  You may have some `map` or other binding interfering with this.

Comment: aargh.  yes, it does work.  Maybe in the original file I had, they weren't actually tabs.  :-(  sorry.